# I've created a submission form but when I hit submit I get the following response

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

```
ERROR: Could not able to execute
INSERT INTO applications (title, surname, maiden_name, first_name, marital_status, gender, country, date_of_birth, address, email, home_numbers, work_numbers, cell_phone, application_results, next_of_kin_name, next_of_kin_relationship, next_of_kin_number, chronic_disease)
VALUES ('Mr', 'McLaren', '', 'Richard', 'Single', 'Male', 'England', '', 'Room 67 14 Tottenham Court Road London England W1T 1JY', 'mclaren.richard@gmail.com', '020 7946 0072', '020 7946 0549', '020 7946 0760', 'Elizabeth', 'Mother', '020 7946 0831', 'No') ).

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 6
```

The php code is:

```
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL

server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cas");



// Check connection

if($link === false){

    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

}



// Escape user inputs for security

$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['title']);

$surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['surname']);

$maiden_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['maiden_name']);

$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);

$marital_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['marital_status']);

$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['gender']);

$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['country']);  

$date_of_birth = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date_of_birth']);

$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);

$home_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['home_number']);

$work_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['work_number']);

$cell_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['cell_phone']);



$next_of_kin_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['next_of_kin_name']);

$next_of_kin_relationship = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['next_of_kin_relationship']);

$next_of_kin_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['next_of_kin_number']);

$chronic_disease = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['chronic_disease']);


// attempt insert query execution

$sql = "INSERT INTO applications (title, surname, maiden_name, first_name, marital_status, 
gender, country, date_of_birth, address, email, home_numbers, work_numbers, cell_phone, 
application_results, next_of_kin_name, next_of_kin_relationship, next_of_kin_number, chronic_disease) 
VALUES ('$title', '$surname', '$maiden_name', '$first_name', '$marital_status', 
'$gender', '$country', '$date_of_birth', '$address', '$email', '$home_number', '$work_number', '$cell_phone', 
'$next_of_kin_name', '$next_of_kin_relationship', '$next_of_kin_number', '$chronic_disease') )";

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){

    echo "Records added successfully.";

} else{

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

}



// close connection

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: This code really makes me twitch.

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT statement had an extra bracket at the end of sentence.

```
INSERT INTO ....  '$chronic_disease') >)< ';
```

INSERT syntax

```
INSERT INTO table(columns) VALUES(values)
```

Comment: Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO applications (title, surname, maiden_name, first_name, marital_status, 
gender, country, date_of_birth, address, email, home_numbers, work_numbers, cell_phone, 
application_results, next_of_kin_name, next_of_kin_relationship, next_of_kin_number, chronic_disease) 
VALUES ('$title', '$surname', '$maiden_name', '$first_name', '$marital_status', 
'$gender', '$country', '$date_of_birth', '$address', '$email', '$home_number', '$work_number', '$cell_phone', 
'$next_of_kin_name', '$next_of_kin_relationship', '$next_of_kin_number', '$chronic_disease')";
```

You had a extra `)` at the end of the above statement.

Comment: No, just accept the answer. As your reputation is low, you might be unable to upvote for now.